# Derivative with respect to a

Tags: derivatives

Any idea about this? 
Given, $\left(\frac{1-a}{x}\right)^2$ and $x$ is a function of $a$, 
what would be the result if I have to differentiate it with respect to $a$?

Comment: In context, a is not a variable but a constant and this is *NOT* a function of a, any more than $(1-7)/x)^2$ is a "function of 7".  However if we do consider $a$ to be a variable and $f(x,a) =( (1-a)/x)^2$ is a two variable function then you have *partial* derivatives.  $df/da = 2((1-a)/x)(-1/x)$ just as one would think.

Comment: sir, a is a variable as well. my apologies.

Comment: Then it is just as you'd think it would be.  $2\frac {1-a}x*-\frac 1x$.

Comment: @migs It would be clearer if you stated the problem as $(\frac{1-x}{f(x)})^2$, as $a$ is traditionally used to represent a constant.

Comment: sir, thanks for the help!

Comment: @migs are you ok with this answer now.

Comment: @Salaham_Fatima, I'm confused as well. since x is a function of a, I believe the partial derivatives don't apply. 

Like what if x(a) is an expression equal to x(a)= 3+a for example.

Answer (score 1):

after the power rule and the chain rule we get
$$2\left(\frac{1-a}{x(a)}\right)\cdot \frac{-x(a)-(1-a)\cdot x'(a)}{x(a)^2}$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/797383)

Comment: i don't understand the question was the derivative with respect to $a$

Comment: Yes it was w.r.t to $a$, written in the title.

Comment: But, "$x$ is a function of $a$", which you seem to have missed.

Comment: better is to write $$\left(\frac{1-a}{x(a)}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da} \left(\dfrac{1-a}{x}\right)^2
&=& 2 \left(\dfrac{1-a}{x}\right) \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da} \left(\dfrac{1-a}{x}\right) \\
&=& 2 \left(\dfrac{1-a}{x}\right) \left(\dfrac{\left[\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}(1-a)\right]x - (1-a)\left[\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm da}x\right]}{x^2}\right) \\
&=& 2 \left(\dfrac{1-a}{x}\right) \left(\dfrac{-x - (1-a)x'}{x^2}\right) \\
&=& \dfrac{2(a-1)(x + (1-a)x')}{x^3} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

It has the form

$$g (a)=(f(a))^2.$$

with $$f (a)=\frac {1-a}{x(a)} .$$
its derivative with respect to $a $ is

$$g'(a)=2f (a)f'(a) $$

where

$$f'(a)=\frac{-x(a)-(1-a)x'(a)  }{ (x(a)^2)  }$$

the result is

$$g'(a)=2 (a-1)\frac{x+(1-a)x'}{x^3} $$

Comment: I took it into account. look well.